# How to handle an array of Promises then/catch

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I don't know to to resolve this situation using JS promises.

Imagine I have some articles and I want to send a patch request to update them. I send one request per article. If the request of one article success then I update that article, but if the request fails, then I update the article differently. Also I want to show a message to the user informing if all the articles have been updated correctly or not.

This is not my real scenario and this may be a weird example. But it's what I want to accomplish in my React app.

Here is what I'm trying to do right now:

```
const saveArticles = articles => {
  const promises = [];

  articles.forEach(article => {
    const promise = axios
      .patch('/articles', article)
      .then(() => updateArticleUi(article))
      .catch(() => updateArticleUiWithError(article));

    promises.push(promise);
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => tellTheUserThereWasNoErrors())
    .catch(() => tellTheUserThereWasSomeErrors());
};
```

This isn't working because the `Promise.all` is always executing the `then` callback, weather all promises succeed or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need Async. Check out this library: https://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateArticleUi` and `updateArticleUiWithErrors` should have the respective return values so that you can distinguish whether there was an error or not when looking at the array of results:

```
function updateArticleUi(article) {
  …
  return {success: true};
}
function updateArticleUiWithError(article, error) {
  …
  return {success: false};
}

function saveArticles(articles) {
  const promises = articles.map(article => {
    return axios.patch('/articles', article).then(() =>
      updateArticleUi(article)
    , err =>
      updateArticleUiWithError(article, err)
    );
  });

  return Promise.all(promises).then(results => 
    if (results.every(res => res.success)) {
      tellTheUserThereWasNoErrors();
    } else {
      tellTheUserThereWasSomeErrors();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```js
function axiosPatchRequest(url,data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (data) {
            resolve(url);
        } else {
            reject('DATA_NOT_FOUND');
        }
    })
}

function updateArticleUi(data,article) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve({type:"updateArticleUi ",data,article});
        
    })
}

function updateArticleUiWithError(data,article) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            reject({type:"updateArticleUiWithError ",data,article});
        
    })
}


function tellTheUserThereWasNoErrors(data){
  console.log("tellTheUserThereWasNoErrors",data);
}

function tellTheUserThereWasSomeErrors(error){
  console.log("tellTheUserThereWasSomeErrors",error);
}

const execute = (articles)=>{
  const promises = [];
articles.forEach(article => {
    const promise = axiosPatchRequest('/articles', article)
      .then((data) => {
          return updateArticleUi(data,article);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          return updateArticleUiWithError(error,article);
          });
      promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .then((data) => tellTheUserThereWasNoErrors(data))
    .catch((error) => tellTheUserThereWasSomeErrors(error));

};

execute(["one","","three"]);
execute(["one","two","three"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` will always call then because the promise you add to `promises` is already resolved one with either `then` or `catch` attached above

if you want to see `catch` to happen in `.all` chain just throw some exeption in `updateArticleUiWithErro` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are catching the error thrown by

```
const promise = axios
      .patch('/articles', article)
      .then(() => updateArticleUi(article))
      .catch(() => updateArticleUiWithError(article));
```

you should either throw a new error in the axios `catch()` or let the error bubble up by removing the `catch` from the axios call.